# Duplicates being created by Webform Submissions

Tags: webform-civicrm

We are seeing issues when users submit a Drupal Webform and accidentally click the submit button twice, duplicate records are being recorded in CiviCRM. This goes for creating 2 of the same contact or assigning 2 event registration to the same contact.

This was never an issue before but seems to have crept in after we upgraded to CiviCRM 5.0.2. We are now on CiviCRM 5.5.3

Using webform_civicrm 7.x-4.21

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

We’ve come across this issue several times in the past and our solution was to use the below Drupal module –

https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit

Comment: Exactly - we use hide submit module for all our projects